# Contract has the wrong name listed as a member of the terms

Tags: digital-contract

I had a client sign their name to a contract for an online service. I had left the typed name of another client on the contract not noticing because they shared the same first name. I have the Client's signature and address correctly on the form and an audio recording confirming he signed it. Is that enough to confirm the contract belonged to him and not the other client whose name I had left on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that enough to confirm the contract belonged to him and not the other client whose name I had left on the form?

Yes. Your evidence would defeat the client's potential denial that he is a party to the contract.

Although irrelevant from a legal standpoint, it is interesting that the inaccuracy went unnoticed to the client as well.

Comment: or did it.......